# Is :not possible on a wildcard attribute selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to use a `:not` selector on a wildcard attribute selector?

Example:

```
<div class="circle circle-red"></div>
<div class="circle circle-blue"></div>
<div class="circle circle-yellow"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

I want to address only the div with class 'circle' and not the divs with class 'circle-red', 'circle-blue', 'circle-yellow'

Comment: Did either answer help you solve the problem? If yes, please consider marking it as accepted (click the hollow tick mark below the voting buttons corresponding to the answer that helped you the most). That is usually the way to mark a problem as "Solved" in SO :)

Answer (score 26):

You can use the negation selector (`:not`) along with the attribute ***contains*** selector for this purpose.

The selector `div.circle:not([class*="circle-"])` will select only the `div` which has the `circle` class but doesn't contain any other class of the format `circle-`.

```css
div.circle:not([class*="circle-"]) {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle circle-red">Red</div>
<div class="circle circle-blue">Blue</div>
<div class="circle circle-yellow">Yellow</div>
<div class="circle">None</div>
<div class="circle-orange">Orange</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can chain :not selectors.

```css
.circle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.circle:not(.circle-blue):not(.circle-yellow):not(.circle-red) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle circle-red"></div>
<div class="circle circle-blue"></div>
<div class="circle circle-yellow"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
```